# Varchar and varbinary error hashbyte

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to write the following in dynamic sql

```
select HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',CONVERT(VARCHAR(256),'String'))
```

---

```
set @sqlstr = 'select ' + HASHBYTES('''SHA2_256''',(CONVERT(VARCHAR 
(256),'String')))
```

But I got error the following error message:

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 The data types varchar and
>   varbinary are incompatible in the add operator.

How will I solve it?

Comment: I do not get it right....I Think I handle the hashbyte wrong

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
declare 
@sqlstr varchar(8000),
@var varchar(8000)

set @var =  HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',CONVERT(VARCHAR(256),'String'))

set @sqlstr = 'select ' + ''''+@var+''''

exec( @sqlstr)
```

or

```
declare 
@sqlstr varchar(8000)



set @sqlstr = 'select  HASHBYTES('+''''+'SHA2_256'+''''+',CONVERT(VARCHAR(256),'+''''+'String'+''''+'))'

exec( @sqlstr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @sqlstr varchar(max)

set @sqlstr = 'select HASHBYTES(''SHA2_256'',(CONVERT(VARCHAR(256),''String'')))  '

exec(@sqlstr)
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear to me at all what you're trying to actually do.  However, you're getting the error you're getting because the return value of [HASHBYTES()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) is varbinary.  The `+` operator isn't defined when the left is varchar like `'select '` and the right is varbinary.

Try:

```
set @sqlstr = 'select ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(66),HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',(CONVERT(VARCHAR(256),'String'))),1)
```